# Hero Siege Relic drop chance

Tags: hero-siege

If i dont pick up relics when they drop. will the chance of encountering a different one still be reduced?

> With Patch v1.4.1.5 the relic system has been re-worked. Obtaining all
>   relics in game is no longer possible, the obtaininig has been limited
>   to a number, each time you pick a relic your chance to get a new one
>   decreases. Due to this system, the singular relics are now much more
>   powerful than before and give out more stats and deal more damage. The
>   rules are as follows
>
> Chance for your first relic is 70% and decreases by 2% with every
>   relic you pick up. So you are technically unable to find more than 35
>   relics. But you can still buy relics in Treasure Fort

Therefore, should i always pick up relics or be selective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way it is worded I would have to say you should be selective since it decreases with every one you **pick up**. Having 35 relics would take a little while to get however so this tactic should only be used by experienced players that will have longer runs where maxing out is an issue. I can see this being somewhat useful if you get a relic you just don't need. However, you can always buy more relics, but they do get *pretty* expensive.